# Is there a way to retrieve the script path called by a user-defined command?

Tags: linux, bash, command, reverse-engineering

I'm a newbie in GNU/Linux and, for a project, I need to do some reverse engineering. At a given line in a script, there is a command:

```
dc 27 /A_PATH/ 32
```

I'm almost sure the "dc" command was previously added to the path/simlink/(?) by a previous developper. When executed, the command allows to run a simulation over the case indicated by the PATH. Yet, I don't know the meaning of the two other parameters (27 and 32) and I would need to bring some change in the way the simulation is executed.

Therefore, I would like to know ***how to obtain the address of the executable called when a user-defined bash command is runned***.

I hope the vocabulary is correct, and, thank you already for the help.

Comment: By 'address', do you mean the PATH ? If yes, : `which dc`

Comment: Also, manpages are your Friends: `man dc`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! 'which' was exactly what I was looking for.
'man' results in the display of a large message without info useful for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments :

```
which <command>
```

or with shell built-in :

```
type -p <command>
```